# jQuery code not working in Firefox/Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var matcheduserID = $('.checkone')[1].matcheduserID;

<input type="checkbox" matcheduserID='user1' class="checkone" onclick="javascript:HoldItem('H')">
```

This code works in Internet Explorer, though in Firefox and Chrome I get it returns undefined.

Comment: Are there multiple elements with class "checkone" ?  Is your jquery code wrapped inside a document.ready?  Can we see more code to figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to access the wrong element in the first place..
Are you trying to access the `First element or the second element` ..

The NodeList is **0 index based**.

If it's the first element you are trying to access then use

```
var matcheduserID = $('.checkone')[0].matcheduserID;
```

Try using the `.getAttribute()` method

**.get(1)**  gets the second element with the given class..

```
var matcheduserID = $('.checkone').get(1).getAttribute("matcheduserID");
```

Maybe you are encountering this issue because `matcheduserID` is not a default attribute for the element

**jQuery**

```
var matcheduserID = $('.checkone:eq(1)').attr('matcheduserID');
```

Comment: Right, and use .get(0) if there is only 1 element instead of [1]

Comment: Why are yall killing jQuery? Its's as easy as `var matcheduserID = $('.checkone').attr("matcheduserID")`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to do this

```
matcheduserID = $('.checkone:first').attr('matcheduserID');
```